# K3S multiple Kube-System pods not running with Unknown Status, including DNS pods

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4, k3s

**Environmental Info:**
K3s Version:
k3s version v1.24.3+k3s1 (990ba0e8)
go version go1.18.1

Node(s) CPU architecture, OS, and Version:
Five RPI 4s Running Headless 64-bit Raspbian, each with following information
Linux  5.15.56-v8+ #1575 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 22 20:31:26 BST 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Cluster Configuration:
3 Nodes configured as control plane, 2 Nodes as Worker Nodes

**Describe the bug:**
The Pods: coredns-b96499967-ktgtc, local-path-provisioner-7b7dc8d6f5-5cfds, metrics-server-668d979685-9szb9, traefik-7cd4fcff68-gfmhm, and svclb-traefik-aa9f6b38-j27sw are at status unknown, with 0/1 pods ready. What this means is that the Cluster DNS service does not work and therefore that pods not are not able to resolve internal or external names

**Steps To Reproduce:**

- Installed K3s in HA mode using following instructions: https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/ha-embedded/

**Expected behavior:**
The Important pods should be running, wit known status. Additionally, DNS should work, which means that, among other things headless services should work, and pods should be able to resolve hostnames inside and outside the cluster

**Actual behavior:**
DNS Pods Should be running with a known state, Pods should be able to resolve hostnames inside and outside the cluster, and headless services should be able to work

**Additional context / logs:**

```
kubectl -n kube-system get configmap coredns -o go-template={{.data.Corefile}}

.:53 {
    errors
    health
    ready
    kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
      pods insecure
      fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
    }
    hosts /etc/coredns/NodeHosts {
      ttl 60
      reload 15s
      fallthrough
    }
    prometheus :9153
    forward . /etc/resolv.conf
    cache 30
    loop
    reload
    loadbalance
}
import /etc/coredns/custom/*.server
```

Description of Relevant Pods:

```
kubectl describe  pods --namespace=kube-system
Name:                 coredns-b96499967-ktgtc
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000000000
Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Node:                 master0/192.168.0.68
Start Time:           Fri, 05 Aug 2022 16:09:38 +0100
Labels:               k8s-app=kube-dns
                      pod-template-hash=b96499967
Annotations:          <none>
Status:               Running
IP:
IPs:                  <none>
Controlled By:        ReplicaSet/coredns-b96499967
Containers:
  coredns:
    Container ID:  containerd://1a83a59275abdb7b783aa06eb56cb1e5367c1ca196598851c2b7d5154c0a4bb9
    Image:         rancher/mirrored-coredns-coredns:1.9.1
    Image ID:      docker.io/rancher/mirrored-coredns-coredns@sha256:35e38f3165a19cb18c65d83334c13d61db6b24905f45640aa8c2d2a6f55ebcb0
    Ports:         53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -conf
      /etc/coredns/Corefile
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Unknown
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Fri, 05 Aug 2022 19:19:19 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 05 Aug 2022 19:20:29 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  8
    Limits:
      memory:  170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     70Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    http-get http://:8181/ready delay=0s timeout=1s period=2s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/coredns from config-volume (ro)
      /etc/coredns/custom from custom-config-volume (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-zbbxf (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      coredns
    Optional:  false
  custom-config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      coredns-custom
    Optional:  true
  kube-api-access-zbbxf:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:                 CriticalAddonsOnly op=Exists
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age                    From     Message
  ----    ------          ----                   ----     -------
  Normal  SandboxChanged  41d (x419 over 41d)    kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal  SandboxChanged  64m (x11421 over 42h)  kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal  SandboxChanged  2m24s (x139 over 32m)  kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.

Name:                 metrics-server-668d979685-9szb9
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000001000
Priority Class Name:  system-node-critical
Node:                 master0/192.168.0.68
Start Time:           Fri, 05 Aug 2022 16:09:38 +0100
Labels:               k8s-app=metrics-server
                      pod-template-hash=668d979685
Annotations:          <none>
Status:               Running
IP:
IPs:                  <none>
Controlled By:        ReplicaSet/metrics-server-668d979685
Containers:
  metrics-server:
    Container ID:  containerd://cd02643f7d7bc78ea98abdec20558626cfac39f70e1127b2281342dd00905e44
    Image:         rancher/mirrored-metrics-server:v0.5.2
    Image ID:      docker.io/rancher/mirrored-metrics-server@sha256:48ecad4fe641a09fa4459f93c7ad29d4916f6b9cf7e934d548f1d8eff96e2f35
    Port:          4443/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      --cert-dir=/tmp
      --secure-port=4443
      --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
      --kubelet-use-node-status-port
      --metric-resolution=15s
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Unknown
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Fri, 05 Aug 2022 19:19:19 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 05 Aug 2022 19:20:29 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  8
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     70Mi
    Liveness:     http-get https://:https/livez delay=60s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    http-get https://:https/readyz delay=0s timeout=1s period=2s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /tmp from tmp-dir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-djqgk (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  tmp-dir:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  kube-api-access-djqgk:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 CriticalAddonsOnly op=Exists
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age                    From     Message
  ----    ------          ----                   ----     -------
  Normal  SandboxChanged  41d (x418 over 41d)    kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal  SandboxChanged  64m (x11427 over 42h)  kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal  SandboxChanged  2m27s (x141 over 32m)  kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.


Name:                 traefik-7cd4fcff68-gfmhm
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000000000
Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Node:                 master0/192.168.0.68
Start Time:           Fri, 05 Aug 2022 16:10:43 +0100
Labels:               app.kubernetes.io/instance=traefik
                      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                      app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik
                      helm.sh/chart=traefik-10.19.300
                      pod-template-hash=7cd4fcff68
Annotations:          prometheus.io/path: /metrics
                      prometheus.io/port: 9100
                      prometheus.io/scrape: true
Status:               Running
IP:
IPs:                  <none>
Controlled By:        ReplicaSet/traefik-7cd4fcff68
Containers:
  traefik:
    Container ID:  containerd://779a1596fb204a7577acda97e9fb3f4c5728cf1655071d8e5faad6a8d407d217
    Image:         rancher/mirrored-library-traefik:2.6.2
    Image ID:      docker.io/rancher/mirrored-library-traefik@sha256:ad2226527eea71b7591d5e9dcc0bffd0e71b2235420c34f358de6db6d529561f
    Ports:         9100/TCP, 9000/TCP, 8000/TCP, 8443/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      --global.checknewversion
      --global.sendanonymoususage
      --entrypoints.metrics.address=:9100/tcp
      --entrypoints.traefik.address=:9000/tcp
      --entrypoints.web.address=:8000/tcp
      --entrypoints.websecure.address=:8443/tcp
      --api.dashboard=true
      --ping=true
      --metrics.prometheus=true
      --metrics.prometheus.entrypoint=metrics
      --providers.kubernetescrd
      --providers.kubernetesingress
      --providers.kubernetesingress.ingressendpoint.publishedservice=kube-system/traefik
      --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls=true
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Unknown
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Fri, 05 Aug 2022 19:19:19 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 05 Aug 2022 19:20:29 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  8
    Liveness:       http-get http://:9000/ping delay=10s timeout=2s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:9000/ping delay=10s timeout=2s period=10s #success=1 #failure=1
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /data from data (rw)
      /tmp from tmp (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-jw4qc (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  tmp:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  kube-api-access-jw4qc:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 CriticalAddonsOnly op=Exists
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age                    From     Message
  ----    ------          ----                   ----     -------
  Normal  SandboxChanged  41d (x415 over 41d)    kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal  SandboxChanged  64m (x11418 over 42h)  kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal  SandboxChanged  2m30s (x141 over 32m)  kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution that I found to resolve the problem - at least for now, was to manually restart all of the kube-system deployments found using the command deployments

```
kubectl get deployments --namespace=kube-system
```

If all of them are similarly not ready they can be restarted using the command

```
kubectl -n kube-system rollout restart <deployment>
```

Specifically, coredns, local-path-provisioner, metrics-server, and traefik deployments all needed to be restarted